# Проблема в области видимости JS

Tags: javascript

номера в отеле вмещают не более 8-ми людей
должен быть минимум один взрослый
на одного взрослого может быть не более двух детей
Считай недостающие аргументы за 0.

Примеры:

```
canTheyBook(0, 2) === false - 0 взрослых, 2 ребенка. Нарушение правил отеля.
canTheyBook(2, 4) === true - 2 взрослых, 4 ребенка. Бронирование разрешено.
canTheyBook(2) === true - 2 взрослых. Бронирование разрешено.
canTheyBook(9) === false - 9 взрослых. Превышено количество людей для одной комнаты.

function canTheyBook(adultsCount, childrenCount) {
  // write code here
  const ad = 0, ch = 0
  if (adultsCount === undefined){
    adultsCount = ad
  }
  if (childrenCount === undefined){
    childrenCount = ch
  }
 {
  if (
    (adultsCount == 0 && childrenCount > 0) || 
    ((adultsCount + childrenCount ) > 8) ||
    (childrenCount > (adultsCount * 2))
  ){
    return false
  }
  }
  return true
}

TEST 6 FAILED
input: adultsCount = 0, childrenCount = undefined
expected output: false

Свернуть
Expected:
false
Received:
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю при чем здесь "Проблема в области видимости JS", но вот рабочий код, который проверяет условия задачи

```
const canTheyBook = (adults = 0, children = 0) => (
  adults > 0 &&
  adults + children <= 8 &&
  children <= adults * 2
);
```

.

```
console.log(
    canTheyBook(),     // false
    canTheyBook(2),    // true
    canTheyBook(9),    // false
    canTheyBook(2, 1), // true
    canTheyBook(2, 5), // false
    canTheyBook(6, 3)  // false
);
```

Comment: нет childrens, есть child (ед.ч.) и children (мн.ч.) :)

Comment: @InDevX, будем-с знать

Comment: `canTheyBook(9, -1)` :)

Comment: @Yaant, отрицательное количество детей - это те, что вместо отеля в детдом едут?)

Answer (score 0):

**Не знаю правильно или нет, но работает)**

```
function canTheyBook(adultsCount, childrenCount) {

  if (adultsCount=== undefined || adultsCount === 0){
    return false;
  }

  if (childrenCount === undefined){
childrenCount = 0;
  }

  if (adultsCount + childrenCount >= 9){
     return false;
  } else if ((adultsCount === 0 && childrenCount > 0 ) || (childrenCount > (adultsCount * 2))){
     return false;
  } else if (adultsCount >= 1 ){
    return true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]